# Cannot access array after coming back from a function which execute with Interrupts STM32 Cube IDE

Tags: stm32, interrupts, stm32cubeide

Hi I am using STM32 Cube IDE to Program Neucleo F746zg board. In my code there is a function to check if the elements of an array is equal to some value and if it is I execute some Functions.

I first Checked this function in the main code and It worked Properly.

```
for (i = 0;i<Length_of_SGSD;i++)
            {


                ///Function 1
                if(array1[i] == 2) // FOOTUP = 2
                {
                    FootUp();
                    int delay_time_foot = (int)array2[i];
                    HAL_Delay(delay_time_foot);

                }
                ///Function 2

                if(array1[i] == 3) //footdown = 3
                {
                    FootDown();

                }



                ////Function 3
                else if(array1[i] == 1) // wait = 1
                {
                    int wait_time = (int)array2[i];
                    HAL_Delay(wait_time);

                }

                ///Function 4

                else if(array1[i] == 4) // Sew = 4
                {

                    Stitch_Count = (int)array2[i];
                    MachineRunWithControlStitch(Stitch_Count ,30);

                }

                ///Function 5
                else if(array1[i] == 5) // Trim = 5
                        {
                            Trim();
                  
                        }

            }
```

This worked properly. Note that the Function 4 gets a checks if a interrupt has occurred and It will increment a variable `value = value + 1;` 
and when its a equal to Stich_Count it will return back to function.
When I run this on my main Program Everything works fine.

But When I make a function from all of these which accepts two arrays as its inputs, a Bus Fault occurs after Function 4 is executed.

The Line where BUS Fault occur is when the new function go to
the Function 4 and It returns back. Then it comes back to the top of the for loop then The program is unable to Access the array. The value i is same as it should be, IDK if the arrays have changed for some reason.(I Do not change arrays in the functions). Any Help on how to solve this would be Much appreciated.

This is the Function I made ,In main I call this

```
 PassArray(arr1,arr2);
```

The Function I made

```
void PassArray(int array1[] , int array2[])
{
//same function as before with array1[] and array2[]
}
```

Comment: Where does Length_of_SGSD come from? Is it constant or do you calculate it in the function?

Comment: Are these arrays large? You're making a copy when passing them to PassArray. Consider passing them by &reference.

Comment: Otherwise the fact that it runs fine in main doesn't mean there is no bug in that case; it could just be that the buggy memory access doesn't use an invalid address.

Comment: @Justme It is a variable with length of these arrays

Comment: @DamienD arrays are not that large. I tried Passing them by reference nothing changed

Comment: @DamienD can you elaborate more on buggy memory address part

Comment: Yes but you don't show the full code so we can't know where the problem is. But mos likely this has nothing to do with STM32, interrupts or CubeIDE, most likely just generic C programming mistake. Pleae answer my question where you calculate the variable and how. Do you do it in the function where you passed the array?

Comment: @Justme the code compiles without an error. Can you point out any programming error that could have happen in a place like this. TBH the full code is so much big and I just shared the relevant parts to it. Most parts are not even slightly related to this problem.

Comment: I could point it out if you would post the code from the relevant parts I have asked. If a code compiles without errors, it just means the compiler has no trouble understanding what you tell it to do. Whether the things you tell it to do make any sense or not.

Comment: int arr1 [] = {1,1,4,1,1};
int arr2 [] = {1000,1000,10,1000,1000};
int Length_of_SGSD = (sizeof (arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]));  @Justme

Comment: Yes buy you never said where you calculated it.

Comment: It is calculated in the  /* USER CODE BEGIN PV */ in main.c file @Justme

Comment: @WedahithaYapa - Hi, I'm not involved with the details of your question, but I saw your comment: "*the full code is so much big and I just shared the relevant parts to it*". It seems you have a much bigger program than shown in your question. In this type of situation, it can be very difficult for others to help, as they cannot see the "whole picture". Please read [this page on Stack Overflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about creating a minimal, reproducible example (a.k.a. MCVE). That helps readers & might help you solve your own problem in the process.

Comment: Thank you all for your help @SamGibson  I figured out the problem. It was a stackflow and fixed it with optimizing the code. Thank you everyone for the help

Comment: @WedahithaYapa - Hi, I'm glad you've solved your problem. Now we have the situation where your question has no answer shown below, but it is solved. Therefore please either: (a) Write your own short answer in the box below, showing the problem in the original code and your solution. You will then be able to "accept" your own answer ("green tick") once 48 hours have passed since you asked the question. Or (b) you can delete your question, if you don't want to write the answer (on a desktop web browser, you will see a link marked "Delete" below the question). Thanks.